# Does it possible for 2 people to work over the internet on one project in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is it possible for 2 people to work over the internet on one project in visual studio ?
Kinda like Google-docs ?
And if so, how can i do it?
(I searched for online tutorials and i didn't find nothing)

Me and my friend have VS 2013.(for general knowledge)

Thank you.

Comment: Search for source control systems: Git, TFS, SVN, ...

Comment: At the same time? You'd be stepping on each other's changes if you're working on the same file in the project.  Take a look at a source control system - there are (I believe) some free ones out there.  Depending on the source control system, you could each take a copy of the project and work on it and then merge the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the [Visual Studio Live Collaboration Tool](https://vsanywhere.com/default.aspx)

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't heard of this before. I could see some use for it (kind of takes pair-programming to a whole new level).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, but not out-of-the-box. You can install a plugin which enables this feature. The plugin is called [VsAnywhere](https://vsanywhere.com/default.aspx) it requires you to register an account for all developers participating. A [2013 compatible version was recently released](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8fdd553-1ec8-4aaf-84d2-f2cf3057ee4b).